# What does $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ in the general solutions of trigonometric equations­ mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wish to understand the meaning of the term $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, in solving trigonometric equations, for example, it is written

> $\theta=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$, for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. I think your question to need more context.

Answer (score 2):

It means that $k$ is an integer.

$\mathbb{Z}$ represents the set of all integers. “$\in$” means “is an element of ”. So, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ means $k$ is an element of the set of all integers.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the set of all integers. The symbol $\in$ means "belongs to". So the statement $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ simply means that $k$ belongs to the set of integers, i.e. $k$ is some unspecified integer. For an example of how this is used: $\cos 2\pi k=1$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\mathbb{Z}$ essentially means *the set of all integers*, while the symbol $\in$ means *belongs to*. Hence, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ means $k$ is an integer.

In the quoted statement, it means that $\theta$ takes all possible values of $2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$, where you can safely put any integer as $k$.

Hope this helps :)